# MagickWand PHP Module DDL for Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, php, imagemagick

I'm struggling with enabling MagickWand as a PHP extension which is ran on Windows (Apache).

I am running PHP 5.3.x.  (I need namespaces).

I have been able to install MagickWand on PHP 5.2.4 but not a 5.3.x.

It appears as though there are NO DLLs for the extension. I don't know how to create a build from the sources either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any information as required.